# umqtt.robust on Wemos

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, micropython

I am trying to install micropython-umqtt.robust on my Wemos D1 mini.
The way i tried this is as follow.
I use the Thonny editor

1. I have connected the wemos to the internet.
2. in wrepl type:

   import upip

   upip.install('micropython-umqtt.simple')
   I get the folowing error: Installing to: /lib/
   Error installing 'micropython-umqtt.simple': Package not found, packages may be partially        installed

   upip.install('micropython-umqtt.robust')
   I get the folowing error: Error installing 'micropython-umqtt.robust': Package not found,   packages may be partially installed

Can umqtt be installed on Wemos D1 mini ? if yes how do I do this ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I work on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the MicroPython build available from micropython.org already bundles MQTT so no need to install it with upip. Try this directly from the REPL:

`from umqtt.robust import MQTTClient`

or

`from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient`

and start using it from there

`mqtt = MQTTClient(id, server, user, password)`

Comment: umqtt is not included by default on all of the MicroPython builds, so this may not work (for example, it is not included in the ESP32-C3 MicroPython distribution, and these imports fail)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help Reilly, 
The way I solved it is as follow. With a bit more understanding of mqtt and micropython I found that the only thing that happens when you try to install umqtt simple and umqtt robust,is that it makes in de lib directory of your wemos a new directory umqtt. Inside this directory it installs two files robust.py and simple.py. While trying to install them I kept having error messages. But I found a GitHub page for these two files, so I copied these files. Made the umqtt directory within the lib directory and in this umqtt directory I pasted the two copied files. Now I can use mqtt on my wemos.